# Map over first element of list of vectors

Tags: clojure

How can I map a function over just the first elements of vectors in a list?

So I have

```
 (["1" "sometexthere" ...]["2" "somemoretext" ...] ....)
```

I need to use read-string to convert the stringy numbers into ints (or longs).

Comment: `(map #(clojure.edn/read-string (first %)) items)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want just the list of results, you can combine the function with `first` and `map` it, as @leetwinski recommended in the comments.

```
(map #(clojure.edn/read-string (first %)) items)
```

If you want to get back the structure you had, but with those particular elements mapped by the function, [`update` and `update-in`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/update) are your friends:

```
(map #(update % 0 clojure.edn/read-string) items)
```

For more involved transformations you may also be interested in [specter](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter)'s `transform`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`comp`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/comp) to compose functions:

```
(require '[clojure.edn :as edn])

(def items [["1" "sometexthere" ,,,] ["2" "somemoretext" ,,,] ,,,])

(map (comp edn/read-string first) items)
;=> (1 2 ,,,)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the `comp` solution by Elogent, however I think for readability I prefer the use of a threading macro:

```
(map #(-> % first clojure.edn/read-string) items)
```

To each his/her own, just my personal preference.